# What are Pajama Man's Superpowers?

Tags: video-games, pajama-sam

In the video game "Pajama Sam", Pajama Sam idolizes a superhero named "Pajama Man".

Other than that he's a superhero who wears pajamas, I don't recall any specific powers attributed to him.

Do we know what Pajama Man's powers are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multiple high-tech gadgets (an [Illuminator Mark V™](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbKlh.png) and a [Portable Bad Guy Containment Unit™](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcaDx.png))**

**Handy-dandy-super-pajama-power-pack™**

**Titanic Elbow Thrust™**

**Bravery and general invulnerability (only weakness is "trapdoors"). Appears to be able to fly.**

[image]

**Pajama Computer™ (for solving crimes)**

[image]

**Pajamobile™**

[image]